# How to get mysql data from php to json?

Tags: php, mysql, json

My problem is to get data from SQL to dynamically update chart.

Mysql data is like this:

```
id | age
1  | 12
2  | 21
3  | 31
4  | 11
5  | 31
```

And I want to echo like this:

```
[1,12] , [2,21] , [3,31] , [4,11] , [5,31]
```

I have tried this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, age FROM tes";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $tes = $row['tes'];
        $a = array($id,$tes);
        echo json_encode($a, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
```

But it ended like this:

```
[1,12] [2,21] [3,31] [4,11] [5,31]
```

Comment: Your desired output isn't valid JSON. Is that exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: If you concatenate JSON strings you don't get JSON, just like concatenating JPEG pictures does not result in a larger picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect all the rows into a 2-D array, then return that as JSON.

```
$a = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $tes = $row['tes'];
    $a[] = array($id,$tes);
}
echo json_encode($a, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```